# Expressing an error $\Delta a$ in terms of $b, c, \Delta b$ and $\Delta c$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am doing an exercise for a course in multivariable calculus; the question is

> In a triangle $ABC$, the angle $A$ is accurately known, but the measurement of the side $b$ is in error by an amount $\Delta b$ and that of side $c$ is in error by an amount $\Delta c$. Find the error in the calculation of side $\Delta a$ in terms of $b, c, \Delta b$ and $\Delta c$.

The cosine rule is

$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc\cos A$$

so we can write

\begin{align}
2a\Delta a &= 2b\Delta b + 2c\Delta c - 2b\Delta c \cos A - 2c\Delta b \cos A\\
a\Delta a&= b \Delta b + c \Delta c - b \Delta c \cos A - c \Delta b \cos A\\
&=\Delta b(b - c\cos A) + \Delta c(c - b\cos A).
\end{align}

I'm not sure how I can reduce this further to get an expression for $\Delta a$ that doesn't involve either $\cos A$ or $a$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are supposed to give an answer independent of $A$ and $a$ I think it would be: $\Delta a = \Delta b + \Delta c$ which is achieved as $A$ approaches $180$ degrees and gives an upper bound in all cases.

Comment: I think $A$ is a fixed value, though this makes sense.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to get any further than simply dividing through by $a = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - 2bc\cos A}$ and just saying something along the lines of "$\cos A$ is a constant so let me get away with that". Thanks for your help though.